# hive query taking infinitely long for execution

Tags: sql, hive

The below hive query is taking an infinitely long time for its execution (more than 3 days). Not sure whether any optimisations in the query would help.

Any suggestions are appreciated !!

```
    select count(distinct(a.custname)) from (
    (select custname, pages, variable
    from table1
    where date_time between "2017-01-01" and "2017-01-31" 
    and (pages in ('Summary', 'Details') 
    or variable in ('Complete', 'Receive'))) a
    left join
    (select custname, pages, variable
    from table1
    where date_time between "2017-01-01 00:00:00" and "2017-01-31 00:00:00" 
    and (pages not in ('Summary', 'Details') 
    and variable not in ('Complete', 'Receive'))) b
    on a.custname = b.custname)
    where b.pages is null
```

Comment: Yo are using variant data format for date_time. What is the column type and if it is string what is the real format?

Answer (score 0):

```
select  count(*)

from   (select      custname

        from        table1

        where       date_time between date '2017-01-01' and date '2017-01-31'

        group by    custname

        having      count
                    (
                        case 
                            when    pages     in ('Summary' ,'Details') 
                                or  variable  in ('Complete','Receive')
                            then    1
                        end
                    ) > 0

                and count
                    (
                        case 
                            when    pages    not in ('Summary'  ,'Details') 
                                and variable not in ('Complete' ,'Receive')
                            then    1
                        end
                    ) = 0
        ) t
```